# While loop failing unityscript

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I just can't seem to get while loops to work for me inside Unity. No matter how simple, Unity always freezes on me.

```
function LoadingLevel (level : int) {

    yield;


    //progressBar.transform.localScale = Vector3(loadingProgress, 0, 0);

    async = Application.LoadLevelAsync(1);

    while (!async.isDone) {

        loadingProgress = parseInt(async.progress * 100);

    }

    //Application.LoadLevel(level); 
}
```

This is what I'm currently having trouble with: it compiles, but freezes at runtime. What am  I doing wrong?

Comment: I see you have been online since I answered this. If it fixed your problem, you're supposed to click the checkmark by the answer. When you do this, it marks the question as answered in the system.

Comment: So did the answer fix your problem or not? If you don't accept answers, people will notice and stop answering your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are failing to understand how async stuff works in Unity.

Your `while` loop needs to `yield`. This is because Unity programs are single-threaded, and `yield` is how you give time to other "coroutines".

```
    while (!async.isDone)
    {
        loadingProgress = parseInt(async.progress * 100);
        yield;
    }
```

Here are the Unity docs on how this works:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html